# Google Sheets Module for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am having an issue with understanding how to implement the Google Sheets API to a module for MagicMirror2.
My biggest issue is not knowing where to put the javascript code from [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/js) to the module creation tutorial found [here](https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror/tree/develop/modules)

I had success with outputting the google spreadsheet information from the node.js google sheet api but I believe I should be using the javascript version of the api.

Is it something as simple as copying the code and pasting it in the getDom() follow by creating the "divs" and other html code via javascript?

I aplogize if this is a horrible question. I have been frustriated with not knowing it and I havent found any other modules for magicmirror that use google sheets api.

Thank you in advance.